# change sql query to find data between a date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code, and it's working fine:

```
$time = time(); 
$todayint=date("Y-m-d", strval($time));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $DB->prefix('cal_event') . " WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_start))='$todayint' OR DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_end))='$todayint' ORDER BY event_organiser ASC";
```

How do I change the code to select data between a date range?

`event_start` and `event_end` are stored as int.

I tried using between but I'm not sure where exactly to put between in the code.

Comment: There are a few ways. One is checking with `=>` and `<=` or `BETWEEN`. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For queries against a single date field, you can make use of the **[`BETWEEN`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between)** operator:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $DB->prefix('cal_event') . " WHERE 
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_time)) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
        ORDER BY event_organiser ASC";
```

And for queries against multiple date fields (like both the start time and end time), you'll want to check `=>` and `<=`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $DB->prefix('cal_event') . " WHERE 
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_start)) >= '$todayint' AND
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_end)) <= '$todayint'
        ORDER BY event_organiser ASC";
```

In both cases you'll want to make use of `AND` rather than `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `BETWEEN` (`column BETWEEN value1 AND value2`)

```
$time = time(); 
$todayint=date("Y-m-d", strval($time));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $DB->prefix('cal_event') 
     . "WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_start))
        BETWEEN '$todayint' AND '$todayint'
        ORDER BY event_organiser ASC";
```

Using `>=` (`column >= value1 AND column <= value2`)

```
$time = time(); 
$todayint=date("Y-m-d", strval($time));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $DB->prefix('cal_event') 
     . "WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_start)) >= '$todayint'
        AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_end)) <= '$todayint'
        ORDER BY event_organiser ASC";
```